# add comment using ajax(from form)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

I want to add comment using ajax. But i faced a problem, that ajax doesn't work. I put `alert` into `success:`, but it doesn't go into success function.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#comment_form").submit(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var url_ = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/addcomment/" + "1" + '/';
          $.ajax({
            url: url_,
            type: "post",
            success: function(result){
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here is my form:

```
<form action="/articles/addcomment/1/" method="post" id = "comment_form">
    <input type = "text" name="commentText" id = "commentText">
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Добавить комментарий" id = "add_comment">
</form>
```

Console error:

```
jquery.min.js:5 POST 127.0.0.1:8000/articles/addcomment/1 403 (FORBIDDEN)
```

Comment: What does the JavaScript error console say? What happens if you add an error handler? What does the Developer Tools Net tab say? Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: Use your browser's inspector to see what comes back from the AJAX request in the Network tab. You will probably see the file colored in red and an exception coming from your page. It'll take you in the right direction of what's going wrong

Comment: jquery.min.js:5 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/addcomment/1/ 403 (FORBIDDEN)

Comment: @Legendary — What? It has one.

Comment: @Andrew — So the server is forbidding access to the URL. That's an error as far as the client is concerned. You'll have to look at the server side code to fine out why it is forbidding access.